# Нужно ли обособлять "почти" как уточнение?

Tags: пунктуация

Лишь некоторая(,) почти незначимая(,) деталь отличала его остальных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны два варианта:

(1) Лишь **некоторая, почти незначимая,** деталь отличала его от остальных. Оборот обособлен со значением дополнительного пояснения.

(2) Лишь **некоторая, почти незначимая деталь** отличала его от остальных. Обозначены однородные отношения: некоторая деталь, почти незначимая деталь. То есть оба определения независимы между собой  и относятся к существительному.